# Where is a sample of some Javascript code for Location Aware Browsing in Firefox 3.5?

Tags: javascript, firefox3.5, location-aware

Does anyone know where I can find an example of some javascript code for the new location-aware features of Firefox 3.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [hacks.mozilla.org](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/geolocation/) and [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation)