# Center Google Map Based on geocoded IP

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps

Basically whenever someones opens up my (Google) map I want it default to their approximate location.

Is there an easy way to do it with Google's API or do I have to write a custom code (this is python based app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://www.ipinfodb.com/. You can get a latitude and longitude value by passing their services an IP address. I did something recently where I created a simple service that grabbed the current IP address and then passed it to the service ("api/location/city" is just a service that curls the ipinfodb service). Using jquery:

```
$.get("api/location/city", null, function(data, textStatus)
{        
    if (data != null)
    {
        if (data.Status == "OK")
        {
            var lat = parseFloat(data.Latitude);
            var lng = parseFloat(data.Longitude);

            $.setCenter(lat, lng, $.settings.defaultCityZoom);

            manager = new MarkerManager(map, {trackMarkers : true });

            var e = $.createUserMarker(map.getCenter());
            e.bindInfoWindowHtml($("#marker-content-event").html());

            var m = [];
            m.push(e);

            // map.addOverlay(e);
            manager.addMarkers(m, 10);
            manager.refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            $.setCenter($.settings.defaultLat, $.settings.defaultLng, $.settings.defaultZoom);
        }
    }
}, "json");
```

The key here is this line:

```
$.setCenter(lat, lng, $.settings.defaultCityZoom);
```

Just setting the center to the lat/lng of the result of the service call.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google API's built-in [ClientLocation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation) object:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
{   
    var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("mapdiv"));

    if (google.loader.ClientLocation) 
    {        
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(
            google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude,
            google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude
        );
        var zoom = 8;

        map.setCenter(center, zoom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html#Initializing_the_Map), just `map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);` or whatever other coordinates.  Doing it in the page's Javascript is normally preferred.

If you mean translating an IP to lat and long, I don't think the Google API supports that, but there are other web services that do, such as [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location), [hostip](http://www.hostip.info/), and many, many others. I don't know which one(s) to recommend -- try out a few, would be my suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If the user uses FireFox 3.5/google gears, you can retrieve the lat and lng from the browser itself.
You'll find details on another [stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177726/where-is-a-sample-of-some-javascript-code-for-location-aware-browsing-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

IP Address Geocoding API for Google Maps: http://web3o.blogspot.com/2011/06/ip-address-geocoding-api-for-google.html

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.